# Using Self joins in Rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, self-join

I have a Users table which also has a manager's id to implement a self-join. when I login as a a manager and click on "My subordinates", I should see my subordinates. The subordinates are also from the User table.
So my question is

1. What should I say here <%= link_to "My Subordinates", ????_path %>(I mean like user_path.).
2. How should the model and controller logic be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like @ryanfelton said, but instead of overwriting the index method, i would create a new one specifically for the subordinates.

```
class Manager::UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :ensure_manager! #this one check the manager_id or any other condition to be manager

    def sobordinates
        @subordinates = @user.subordinates
    end

end

#routes.rb
namespace :manager do
    resources :users do
        collection do
            get :subordinates
        end
    end
end
```

This way you can maintain the index of users and you have a method only for the subordinates.

Be aware that you need to create a subordinates.html.erb inside the users folder >
`app/views/manager/users/subordinates.html.erb`

EDIT:
You where asking for the model and the link also so, here it goes:

The link: after editing the routes.rb, go to the console and use `rake routes`
and search for the subordinates link. Add the _path or _url depending on the use you are whiling for that path.

The model, I strongly recommend you to read the official documentation about relations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html. That would help you more than having the answer for copying and pasting :)

Comment: Implemented this. Took a really long time to understand all this. But was worth it :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend namspacing a `users_controller.rb`.

So it would be in the folder `app/controllers/manager/users_controller.rb`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :ensure_manager!

  def index
    @manager.users
  end
end
```

In the `routes.rb` you would have this route:

```
namespace :manager do
  resources :users
end
```

So ultimately your path would be `manager_users_path`

Comment: It says "Unable to autoload constant Manager::UsersController, expected /home/nitrous/pms/app/controllers/manager/users_controller.rb to define it"